# LUKS Cryptsetup Options Failing for Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ Running Kali Linux ARM

Tags: linux, encryption, raspberry-pi, kali-linux, luks

I've scoured the internet for help on this, and it seems I'm one of the only people with this problem.

I recently downloaded a fresh copy of Kali Linux ARM for the Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+, and I want to set it up as a portable hacking station with an external encrypted media drive (encrypted with LUKS) that will be automatically unlocked at boot. I configured `/etc/fstab` and `/etc/crypttab` to correctly unlock and mount my encrypted partitions respectively (using a key file).

I noticed that this process would consistently fail on boot, giving the error that it "cannot allocate memory" when unlocking the drive through `/etc/crypttab`. After doing some more digging and testing, I found that the problem was only on the Raspberry Pi itself, because I could use the exact same key file to unlock the drive manually on my laptop: `cryptsetup luksOpen --key-file /root/keyfile /dev/sdb1 sdb1_crypt`. When I tried this same command on the Raspberry Pi, it would wait for a few seconds (just as it did on my laptop while it took time to unlock the drive), and finish with a successful error code. However, the drive would not be unlocked, and running `lsblk` would still show the locked drive (it also did not appear in `/dev/mapper/sdb1_crypt`), whereas the drive would be successfully unlocked when done on my laptop. The `luksRemoveKey` command also did not work on the Raspberry Pi. I didn't try every `cryptsetup` command, but I'm convinced that those aren't the only ones that don't work. Nevertheless, I could still use my password (key slot 0, and the key file was key slot 1) to unlock the drive on both devices: `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb1 sdb1_crypt`.

My guess is that the problem lies with the kernel, and I don't have the skills to fix it. I thought about posting this over at the Kali Linux forums, but I was hoping someone else might have the same problem on another OS that they fixed.

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I did a little more research into the memory warnings `cryptsetup` was giving me, and I found [this post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=224013#p1436131) by @rscottbailey.

> It turns out cryptsetup chooses some parameters that effectively are scaled based on the performance of your current system (in an attempt to reach some vaguely consistent level of "hardness"?) -- what works well for the Core i7 is too difficult for my Raspberry Pi.
>
> My workaround, since I didn't have any data on the device yet that I couldn't regenerate, was to repeat the formatting operation on the rpi 3. This gave me something that was usable on both systems.

After reformatting my drive and creating a new LUKS partition from my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+, the errors ceased to occur. To anyone else looking to create an encrypted LUKS partition on any external/portable drive, I suggest you encrypt it using the slowest/lowest-capacity device you have.